# useState not Updating on screen in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

The Output is not changing on the screen as expected
My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import ListItem from "../components/ListItem";

import colors from "../config/colors";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import ListItemSeperator from "../components/ListItemSeperator";
import ListItemDeleteAction from "../components/ListItemDeleteAction";

const InitialMessages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "T1",
    description: "D1",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "T2",
    description: "D2",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "T3",
    description: "D3",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
];

function MessagesScreen(props) {
  const [messages, UpdateMessageArray] = useState(InitialMessages);

  const handlerDelete = (message) => {
    console.log("Came to Delete");
    const newArr = messages.filter((m) => m.id !== message.id);
    UpdateMessageArray(newArr);
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <FlatList
        data={InitialMessages}
        keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={item.title}
            subTitle={item.description}
            image={item.image}
            onPress={() => console.log("MESSAGE PRESSED", item)}
            renderRightActions={() => (
              <ListItemDeleteAction onPress={() => handlerDelete(item)} />
            )}
          />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeperator}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default MessagesScreen;
```

On the console..it outputs as "CAME TO DELETE" and I also logged the initialMessages array after every deletion...I saw it gets updated but not on the screen.
Any Idea why its not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlatList is a **PureComponent**.

It needs a **props** which is changed in order to re-render. You set your `data` props as `InitialMessages` and not `messages` so there is no state change.

Please set your data props with `messages` state or else use extraData props to pass some state which can be changed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View } from "react-native";
import ListItem from "../components/ListItem";

import colors from "../config/colors";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import ListItemSeperator from "../components/ListItemSeperator";
import ListItemDeleteAction from "../components/ListItemDeleteAction";

const InitialMessages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "T1",
    description: "D1",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "T2",
    description: "D2",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "T3",
    description: "D3",
    image: require("../assets/Images/mosh.jpg"),
  },
];

function MessagesScreen(props) {
  const [messages, UpdateMessageArray] = useState(InitialMessages);

  const handlerDelete = (message) => {
    console.log("Came to Delete");
    const newArr = messages.filter((m) => m.id !== message.id);
    UpdateMessageArray(newArr);
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <FlatList
        data={messages}
        keyExtractor={(message) => message.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={item.title}
            subTitle={item.description}
            image={item.image}
            onPress={() => console.log("MESSAGE PRESSED", item)}
            renderRightActions={() => (
              <ListItemDeleteAction onPress={() => handlerDelete(item)} />
            )}
          />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeperator}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default MessagesScreen;
```

Reference 1: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html

Reference 2: [Why FlatList is not updating dynamically in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621316/why-flatlist-is-not-updating-dynamically-in-react-native)

Comment: @KartikeyVaish done...just need to change data={InitialMessages} into data={messages} which is your React state.